# Java Generics super/extends - different behaviors (for OCP java 8 study purposes)

Tags: java, generics, lambda, extends, super

Suppose I have the following structure:

```
java.lang.Object
class A extends Object { public boolean mA() {return true;} }
class B extends A { public boolean mB() {return false;} }
```

Now I'm writing a main method to use it.
I'm fine with the concepts below: ('Object' type returning from the get method for super)

```
public static void m1(List<? super A> l ) {
    l.get(0).toString();
}
```

since I can call it using

```
m1(new ArrayList<A>());
m1(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

I'm also fine with this: ('A' type returning from the get method for extends)

```
public static void m2(List<? extends A> l ) {
    l.get(0).mA();
}
```

since I can call it using

```
m2(new ArrayList<A>());
m2(new ArrayList<B>());
```

**Finally my question: why does the definition below with 'super' receive type 'A' as parameter, instead of Object?**

```
Predicate<? extends A> p1 = a -> a.mA(); // ok
Predicate<? super A> p2 = a -> a.mA(); // why is it of type 'A' too??
```

I thought it would turn into something like (I know the code below is invalid... I'm just thinking it would be similar to that).

```
PredicateImpl<T super A> {
    public boolean test(T t);
}
```

I also checked the decompiled class but I didn't get any new clue. Can anyone tell me what is happening under the hood? I already read PECS discussions but it didn't help me on this specific matter.

Thank you in advance!  ;)

===== Editing with extra code after receiving the answer =====

```
Predicate<? super A> pSuper = a -> a.mA();
Predicate<? extends A> pExtends = a -> a.mA();      // ?? A ??

Predicate<Object> pObject = o -> o.equals(null);
Predicate<A> pA = a -> a.mA();
Predicate<B> pB = b -> b.mB();

pSuper = pObject;
pSuper = pA;
pSuper = pB;        // compiler error

pExtends = pObject; // compiler error
pExtends = pA;
pExtends = pB;
```

Interesting alternative syntax (although I think Predicate<? extends Anything> is pretty useless, as it only accepts 'null' at the test method). Anyway I'm finding exercises like this and I have learn it regardless.

```
Predicate<? extends A> pExtends2 = (B b) -> b.mB();
```

Comment: Good question! I never noticed this, but it seems really interesting! I wish I could help but I don’t know much about the implementation of genetics in Java. But realize that Generics are all compile time, they get reduced to Object during bytecode generation. Generics are only for ease of use for programmers.

Comment: Well it can't be an `Object` because you're calling `mA()`.  Try calling `toString()` and see what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JLS, Section 9.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9), talks about the type inference of lambda expressions.  One of the sections talks about type inference in the presence of wildcards and bounds.

> When a generic functional interface is parameterized by wildcards, there are many different instantiations that could satisfy the wildcard and produce different function types. For example, each of `Predicate<Integer>` (function type `Integer` -> `boolean`), `Predicate<Number>` (function type `Number` -> `boolean`), and `Predicate<Object>` (function type `Object` -> `boolean`) is a `Predicate<? super Integer>`. Sometimes, it is possible to known from the context, such as the parameter types of a lambda expression, which function type is intended (§15.27.3). Other times, it is necessary to pick one; in these circumstances, **the bounds are used**.

(bold emphasis mine)

Here, with the target type of `Predicate<? super A>`, multiple possible types for the lambda parameter `a` are possible: `Object` and `A`.  The target type bound is `? super A`, so the bound `A` is used as the type.

This makes the most sense for any wildcard bound, upper or lower.  With an upper bound, the bound type makes perfect sense.  The type is `A` or lower, but it could be just `A`, so `A` methods should be available.  A `Predicate<A>` is assignable to a `Predicate<? extends A>`.

With a lower bound, the type is `A` or higher.  But why not pick `Object`?  Because `A` works just fine.

A `Predicate<A>` can be assigned to a `Predicate<? super A>`.  A `Predicate<Object>` can also be assigned to a `Predicate<? super A>`, but that would be unnecessarily restrictive.  The lambda expression would be restricted to calling `Object` methods, when it could easily call `A` methods as you have written (method `mA`).  It makes sense to pick the most restrictive type possible here, so that the most methods are available to the programmer to call.  Besides, a functional interface type that is the most restrictive according to the bounds has to be assignable.  A `Predicate<A>` is assignable to `Predicate<? super A>`.

You could even assign the lambda expression `a -> a.mA()` to a `Predicate<? extends B>`, a `Predicate<? super B>`, or even a `Predicate<B>`.  The inferred type is `B`, and that type certainly has the method `mA`, inheriting it from `A`.

If you were to try to assign the lambda expression `a -> a.mA()` to a `Predicate<Object>` or a `Predicate<?>`, then `Object` must be the inferred type.  Here, you would get the compiler error about `mA` not being defined on `Object`.

Comment: That's basically the core. I think that [15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3) and [18.5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.3) could also be relevant, but ... it's already hard enough to wrap one's head around that.

Comment: Thank you @rgettman. When you mentioned the 'assignable' part it made sense to me. The code format tag is not working for me here so I'll add some other lines that I used to test your answer at the question section, plus an interesting syntax I found while researching more of this.